# Pack .EXE in Wix Installer and execute after installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm creating an installer for my application using the wix toolset.

I need to include an .EXE file and execute it during/after the installation process (the .EXE shall not be installed to the application folder).
The .EXE also has a dependency on a .DLL file, which came with the .EXE file.

How can I accomplish this?

Greets

Comment: This should work: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372978/wix-customaction-execommand-hide-console

Comment: Are you sure what this works when the .EXE file has a dependency on a .DLL file? Also, how do I add the exe and dll to my project exactly?

Comment: Yes because it executes after it is installed.

Comment: As mentioned in my question: The .EXE file shall NOT be installed during installation process. It is not part of my application. It should only run once during installation process to change some registry entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work ...

```
<CustomAction Id         ="echo_test"                     
              Directory  ="INSTALLLOCATION"
              ExeCommand ='NOTEPAD.EXE echo_test.txt'
              Execute    ="immediate"
              Return     ="asyncNoWait"
                    />
```

Taken from: [Call command line after installation in Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609012/call-command-line-after-installation-in-wix)

Comment: I decided to use this approach. The installer copys the .EXE and .DLL in the install directory and runs the .EXE.
Running the .EXE during the installation process is not possible because of the .DLL dependency!