# Run an external exe before Wix installer finished

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using wix to make a installer. The application uses ReportViewer2010 and we do not want to change it. So, we want to install the application and run the microsoft ReportViewer2010 redistribution in the installer.

```
<CustomAction Id="RunReportViewer2010Redistribution" 
Directory="ReportsFolder" 
ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start ReportViewer.exe" 
Return="asyncNoWait" />    

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action ="RunReportViewer2010Redistribution" After="InstallFinalize">        
  </Custom>      
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This works fine. However, it pops a cmd window although it closes itself. Is there a way so that the cmd window won't popup?

Thanks

*** tried
[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start ReportViewer.exe & exit

does not work. the cmd window still pops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiX - CustomAction ExeCommand - Hide Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372978/wix-customaction-execommand-hide-console)

Comment: no, the answer in that does not work for me.

Comment: If it requires elevation you'll need to run it deferred before InstallFinalize

Answer (score 0):

I recently done something similar in my own installer (silent, deferred, using other windows installer properties) using the documentation at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html.

The first example seems to be what you are looking for.